# Apache2 on Ubuntu 11.04 - New Virtual Host 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, symlink

I receive the following error when trying to access a new virtual host:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.2.17
>   (Ubuntu) Server at www.local.ttr Port 80

The apache log file for this virtual host contains the following error:

> [Tue Aug 09 13:54:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link
>   not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/ttr

I have set up a .conf file in sites-available and created a symlink to this in sites-enabled. This file has the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/ttr/Public/public"
    ServerName www.local.ttr
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/ttr-public-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/ttr-public-access.log" common
php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 30719
    php_value error_log /var/www/ttr/Public/application/logs/logs.txt
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/var/www/ttr/Public/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The path /var/www/ttr is a symlink to a folder within my home directory /home/gordon/ttr which contains all projects including a project called Public.

Could anyone give me any pointers on how to fix this problem? It is driving me berserk!

Answer (score 1):

Apache should have execute permission for /home/gordon/ttr [and everythng in there]